# Property of type dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Is there a way to declare a property of type dictionary of string, string in VB.Net.
I am using this on a usercontrol to add properties via the designer.

I tried the following:

```
Private v As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Property VList As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get
            Return v
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of String, String))
            v = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

But when I try this the string collection editor window opens up but the add & remove buttons are disabled. What is the correct way to declare this property?

I want to add the key & value via the designer.

Comment: You may need a custom designer for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h51z5c0x.aspx

Comment: if you define a class as `{Name As String, Value As String}` then expose a property As `List(Of myTypeClass)` the proper UITypeEditor should open for it.  a few attributes will be needed here and there for desinger serialization though.  If the class really is that simple, you can likely not have to write a TypeConverter either.

Comment: I tried this but on the designer my property seems to be grayed out..

Comment: Side issue, but it's often best to remove the Set from this kind of property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dictionary` does not have a built in `UITypeEditor`.  There are  many reasons why there isn't: there are 2 Types which are generic, it also doesnt have an `Item` accessor, there is no simple `Add` method, the key must be unique and there is no built in way to serialize a Dictionary "item".

The *right* way is to use a Collection class inheriting from `Collection<T>` so you can control access to the contents (note: this is from `System.Collections.ObjectModel` **not** the horrible VB Collection!).  The *fast way* to setup a working interface is to use a `List(Of myTypeClass)`, but this is dangerous in production code because it allows all sorts of actions on the innerlist which you likely do not want.

```vb
<Serializable><TypeConverter(GetType(FooConverter))>
Public Class FooBar
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    Public Property Name As String
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    Public Property Value As String

   ' simple ctor REQUIRED for the UITypeEditor
   Public Sub New()
       Name = ""
       Value = ""
   End Sub

   ' ctor for the TypeConverter (NOT included)
   Public Sub New(n As String, v As String)
       Name = n
       Value = v
   End Sub

  Public Overrides Function ToString
      Return Name
  End Sub
End Class

' must be instanced
Private myFoo As New List(Of FooBar)

' list is an object so it cant be serialized, but the CONTENTS can be
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public Property FooList As List(of FooBar)
  Get
     If myFoo Is Nothing Then
         myFoo = New List(of FooBar)
     End If
     Return myFoo
  End Get
  Set
     ' do nothing
  End Set
End Sub

' for designer serialization
Private Function ShouldSerializeFooList As Boolean
    Return myFoo.Count > 0   ' or myFoo IsNot Nothing
End Sub

public Sub ResetMyFolist
  myFoo = New List(of FooBar)
End Sub
```

---

Caveats:

It is almost always better to write a class container for the Foobar items.  Usually you would inherit from `Collection<T>`. `List<T>` as shown is a container and a collection, so the contents can be cleared, reset, modified etc when exposed as shown. They are fast and easy to implement though and the basic concept is the same.

If a Dictionary is really what you want, you can write your own `UITypeEditor` (not UIDesigner, this is not a control) but this would probably require a great deal of work on many levels.  The reason there are not gobs of them flying around is that most people make do with one of the standard collections and simply enforce unique names in other ways.  (Adding "Properties" to a usercontrol, suggests that really the `key` or name ought to be fixed and known to the app ahead of time so it knows what it is and what to do with it(?)).

Often VS can perform designer serialization on its own with simple properties like those in `FooBar`.  However, since they are items in a collection, you will likely need to also write a `TypeConverter` which can return an `InstanceDescriptor`, to help VS instance them.  But that is a different question.

Comment: Yes the keys will be fixed. I need to set the values for these keys from the designer. I have only used simple properties of type boolean, integer and string before, so using a collection is pretty new. Can you suggest a simple example code for a beginner. I need to create a property which has a list of defined keys & their values need to be editable from the designer. Both key & value could be string.

Comment: So if the keys/property names are fixed and known, why are they in any sort of collection at all?  Why arent they plain old regular properties? There **are** ways to restrict a class property value (ie name/key in this case), but if they are in a collection the user can add multiples of them which is probably not desirable either.  How many of these things are there, and why not standard, fixed props? @crazy_PHP_MAN

Comment: sorry I was a bit confused, I need to define both the key and value from the designer. This thing is driving me crazy..........! :) sry abt that.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to define a list of validations that are available for a textbox usercontrol. Eg: decimal=2 and mandatory=true. At the moment I have a string & I am splitting it at runtime. This seems a bit of waste. So I am trying to define it as a key value straight away from the designer..

Comment: Now, it sounds like maybe you just need a collection of "Rules" where an "Action" property is predefined (DecimalPlaces, Mandatory, MinVal, MaxVal, StartsWith, Equals, MoreThan etc etc etc).  Maybe more than one type of Rule (or action) to account for Text vs Value vs Date type TBs.  The user then just stacks up the rules in the order they want them performed.

Comment: the above answer **is** a start.  a) Change the List<T> to a collection class then b) start modifying `FooBar` to implement a Name (str), ValidationAction (enum probably) and Value (str) properties.  The exact makeup depends on the universe of actions you wish to implement - think that thru carefully so you only have to build it once.  Then when you get stuck post a new question.  The above is cribbed from just such a mechanism (define a set of Filters based on various criteria like Min, Max, ==, != etc).

Comment: @crazy_PHP_MAN I also figured out over the weekend while working on something else that NET has "issues" serializing Dictionaries.  which is probably why they do not have a built in UITypeEditor.  I am curious why this still isnt checked off since much of the pattern presented above is now present in your code on subsequent questions.

Comment: sry abt that. I upvoted instead of accepting it.. :)